# Trigger error when converting a Lead

Tags: apex, trigger

> Error: There was an error converting the lead. Please resolve the
>   following error and try again: LeadConTrigger: execution of
>   BeforeUpdate caused by:
>
> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1
>   Trigger.LeadConTrigger: line 4, column 1

I get the above error when converting a lead, using the trigger below. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
trigger LeadConTrigger on Lead(before update, after update){

    for(Integer i = 0 ; i <= Trigger.new.size() ; i++){
        if(Trigger.new[i].isConverted == TRUE){
            Set<Id> idSLead = new Set<Id>();
            for(Lead lead : Trigger.new){
                idSLead.add(lead.Id);
                System.debug('Check: ' + idSLead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are using conventional for-loop. Also, you don't need two for loops here only one is sufficient.

the problem is on this line

```
for(Integer i = 0 ; i <= Trigger.new.size() ; i++){
```

which should be

```
for(Integer i = 0 ; i < Trigger.new.size() ; i++){
```

However, you can use modern for-loop here. so the full and final code will be

```
trigger LeadConTrigger on Lead(before update, after update){

    Set<Id> idSLead = new Set<Id>();
    for(Lead lead : Trigger.new){

        if(lead.isConverted){
            idSLead.add(lead.Id);
            System.debug('Check: ' + idSLead);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B. `if(lead.IsConverted) { ` is sufficient and best practice for sobject Boolean fields)

Comment: yeah thanks for pointing out. I always tend to forget that, updating.